# How to inject a Service into another Service in Angular2 >= 2.0.0-rc6?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

Duplication note: Most questions + according answers to the same topic are based on Angular2 <= v2.0.0-rc4. With rc5 the old Module/Provider API was deprecated and in rc6 removed, so those answers don't apply anymore.

Question is: How do I inject an angular2 service into another service class? Singe Services are not `@Component()`s they don't have the "prodivers" metadata field. And in angular2 >= rc6 adding the service as a dependency into the `bootstrap()` function doesn't work anymore. So how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All providers added to `providers: []` of an `@NgModule()` are made available globally (except for lazy loaded modules). So if `Service1` needs to inject `Service2` this is enough:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [Service1, Service2],
  // or
  imports: [SomeModule] // where `SomeModule` contains above providers
})
class AppModule {}
```

You can also add the providers to components.

```
@Component({
   providers: [Service1, Service2]
})
```

Comment: I thought so but listing the Service in the providers section of the `@Ngmodule` declaration doesn't seem to work for me. Adding a custom module to the `imports` section should be unnecessary if both services are within the same `@NgModule`s ?

Comment: It needs to be imported "somewhere" (transitive imported by the root module where all of the modules in between are **not** lazy loaded), otherwise noting of the module will be loaded.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks, that was a typo. Should be `AppModule`

Comment: The solution doesn't work for me. What does work is putting the Service as a provider in to the `providers` field of my root `AppComponent` object

Comment: This works for sure. There is something else wrong in your app.

Comment: Or you provide a plunker that shows how it not works and I see if I can fix it ;-)

Comment: Just pressing the "new" button in Plunker should you provide a proper template for Angular2 TS or the "live example" link in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Set up a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/AOJwFN0f0slXKVUpVu6V?p=preview  In the plnkr, not even adding the services to the `providers` of the `AppComponent` works :(

Comment: Moving the services to their own files seems to have fixed it http://plnkr.co/edit/dNaVtwt2TZaKNTaZFMig?p=preview

Comment: This is totally weird. How come it does matter in what files I declare my classes?!? Seems like an angular2 bug. Anyways, accepting your answer now.

Comment: Hard to tell. TS has sometimes issues with imports and dependencies between classes when they are not in their own file. The dependencies in your Plunker seems too simple to cause such issues though.